# Horizontal CSS columns with fixed header

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

How can I arrange horizontal columns with fixed top header on each text block?
Text blocks overlaps each other on overflow.

I want to see like on this screenshot
[image: screenshot]

You can see the problem at [**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1x22mtkt/)

or this:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.column {
    outline: 1px dotted green;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    column-width: 100vw;
    width: min-content;
    min-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    column-span: all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit..</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dicta aut a at sunt quasi aspernatur. Ullam porro, consequatur est quo voluptatum atque. Delectus, dicta, saepe? Delectus sapiente officiis soluta maiores voluptatum voluptates culpa. Libero consectetur aliquid temporibus, dignissimos</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="header">Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, explicabo.</p>
     </div>
     
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="header">Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
     </div>
     
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="header">Lorem</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Or what does another way exist?

Comment: you have 4 columns, and they're all set to min-width 50%, so effectively your total minimum width is 200% of the available space. don't complain your 1 liter cup overflowed when you tried to pour in 2 liters...

Comment: I don't know how many I have columns or text. But I need to arrange its one after another. Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/1x22mtkt/1/

Check this out. You can adjust the **min-height** according to your need. my suggestion would be to set it to what your largest column would be so that each column would be of same size.

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
  
    width: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.column {
   outline: 1px dotted gray;
     min-height:230px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
    column-width: 100vw;
    width: min-content;
    min-width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
     
}

.column p{
  word-break: break-all;
}

.header {
    column-span: all;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```